# How to determines whether two integers are even or odd

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Can I check if anyone able to give advice for my coding below?

I am trying to enter 2 integers and the program will read if e.g 2 and 2 is even, 3 and 3 is odd, lastly if 2 and 3 it will print one is even the other is odd.

```py
def q6():
    
    num1 = int(input("Enter One Number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter Second Number: "))
    
    if (num1 % 2) == 0:
        if (num2 % 2) == 0:
            print("The Numbers are Even")
            
        else:
            print("One Number is Even and the other is Odd")
            
    else:
        print("The Numbers are Odd")
q6()
```

**Output 1:**
Enter One Number: 2
Enter Second Number: 5
One Number is Even and the other is Odd

**Output 2:**
Enter One Number: 2
Enter Second Number: 2
The Numbers are Even

**Output 3:**
Enter One Number: 3
Enter Second Number: 3
The Numbers are Odd

**Output 4:**
Enter One Number: 5
Enter Second Number: 16
The Numbers are Odd

It seems to be working, but under Output 4 it suppose to be "One Number is Even the other is Odd" but it doesn't work very well seems I am missing something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is not checking all four combinations.  I would use this logic:

```
if (num1 + num2) % 2 == 1:
    print("One Number is Even and the other is Odd")
elif num1 % 2 == 0 and num2 % 2 == 0:
    print("The Numbers are Even")
else:
    print("The Numbers are Odd")
```

Note that the first condition if the above `if` block rests on that an odd number plus an even number will always result in an odd number, whose mod 2 remainder will be 1.

Comment: I see! It is working well now! Thanks a lot for your guidance!